# Contradicting theorems about homology of spheres?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

In Rotman's Algebraic topology there are two theorems:

> Let $S^n$ be the $n$-sphere, where $n \ge 0$.  Then $H_p(S^0) = \Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z$ if $p = 0$, and $H_p(S^0) = 0 $ if $ p \gt 0$.

and

> If $X$ is a nonempty path connected space, then $H_0(X) \approx \Bbb Z$.

By the second theorem, $S^0$ is nonempty and path connected, therefore $H_0(S^0)= \Bbb Z$.

By the first theorem, if $p = 0$ then $H_0(S^0) = \Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z$.

But $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z \approx \Bbb Z$ is not true.

Can someone explain to me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space $ S^0 $ is not path-connected.  Recall the definition of the 0-sphere, $ S^0 = \{ a \in \mathbb{R}^1 : \left\lvert a \right\rvert = 1 \} = \{ \pm 1 \} $.  So the 0-sphere consists of 2 disconnected points.